# Can websites detect web scraping if I act like a human (Selenium, Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use Selenium in Python and I want to scrape a lot of websites from one company (many hundreds). But that shouldn't burden the system under any circumstances and because this is a very large website anyway, it shouldn't be a problem for them.

Now my question is if the company can somehow discover that I'm doing web scraping if I'm acting like a human. That means I stay on a website for an extra long time and allow extra time to pass.

I don't think you can recognize me by my IP, because the period of time is very long while I do this and I think it looks like normal traffic.

Are there any other ways that websites can see that I am doing webscraping or generally running a script?

Many Thanks

*(P.S.:I know that a similar question has already been asked, but the answer was simply that he doesn't behave like a human and visits the website too quickly. But it's different for me ...)*

Comment: Some website can detect you using web bot because webdriver have its specific fingerprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scraping make sure that you respect the robots.txt file which is based at the root of the website. It set the rules of crawling: which parts of the website should not be scraped, how frequently it can be scraped.

User navigation patterns are monitored by large companies to detect bots and scraping attempts. There are many anti scraping tools available in market which are using AI to monitor the various patterns to differentiate between a human and a bot.

Some of the main techniques used to prevent scraping apart from software are

Captcha,
Honey traps,
UA monitoring,
IP monitoring,
Javascript encryption, etc..

There are many more, so what i am saying is that yes it can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

One way they can tell is from your browser headers